# VBScript - Putting Array Element into GetElementById

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a VBScript that automatically interacts with some web pages. I am having trouble at the final step where the script needs to click on a link to make a booking. The link for each time will only be available if that time is free. The idea of my code is to simply select the first time available (I originally though I could do this by using Mid() and GetElementId as I know the first 7 chars of each link ID but couldn't get this working). The array contains the IDs for all possible times available in a day. Some will already have been taken so that ID will no longer exist on the form.

I have 2 problems:-

1) Neither getElementBy Id or the Document.All.Item().Click commands will accept an element from the array - I get an Object Required run time error.

2) If getElementId doesn't find a matching ID it simply throws an Object required error. I wasn't expecting this, I thought that my elem variable would be nothing or null and that I could test for this.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

```
'This is a shortened version of my array- there are lots more times!
Times(0)="bookBtn0810"
Times(1)="bookBtn0818"
Times(2)="bookBtn0826"

Dim TimeAvail
Dim i
Dim elem

TimeAvail = "No"
i = 0

Do While (TimeAvail = "No") or (i<3)
  Set elem = IE.Document.GetElementById(Chr(34) & Times(i) & Chr(34)) 'Chr(34) is to add ""
  if elem is nothing then
      TimeAvail = "No"
      i=i+1
  else 
      TimeAvail = "Yes"
      IE.Document.All.Item(Chr(34) & Times(i) & Chr(34)).click
  end if
Loop
```

Comment: do you really need the `Chr(34)`s?

Comment: I'm a little confused by the "Set elem = IE.document.get" - do you need the "set" and the "ie."?

If the ID doesn't exist, throwing an error is the behaviour I'd expect. 

What are you running this code in an hta? wscript? A webpage? cscript?

Comment: I assumed I would need the Chr(34) in order to include the double quote characters when passing each array element into the get ElementById and click methods.

Comment: @DoctorTrout - Yes, that's the thing. The IDs may not exist as the times they represent may already have been taken. I figured I'd need to test for the existence of each possible time / Id before trying to click. I was under the impression that I could test for an empty object by setting a variable. I'm running the script from a vbs file on my PC.

Comment: i think you should remove the `Chr(34)`s and see if that gets you anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Now, unless I'm being very silly, you won't be able to sit a variable to a non-existent element.

The only thing I can think of is to add:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

At the beginning, so it skips the error message. You may need to handle the error separately yourself.